# the_content() is not displaying content, why?

Tags: themes, customization, the-content

I have a custom theme and have built a blog page where I'd like to utilize "the loop", but get_content() is not working. Instead of displaying page content, it displays code from a template. I don't understand why this doesn't function properly, because get_posts(), the_time(), and the_title() all work fine... here's what  my code looks like:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>


        <div id="bottom-wrapper-page">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
            {
                bcn_display();
             }?>
         </div><!--.breadcrumbs-->
         <div id="delimeter"></div>

        <!--[if IE ]><div id="ie"><![endif]-->
        <!--[if !IE]>--><div id="post"><!--<![endif]-->            

            <?php if( is_page('blog') ) { 
             $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed

              while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <div id="bp">
             <?php
               $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
             foreach($myposts as $post) :
             ?>
              <div class="bl_date"><?php the_time('d/m/y'); ?>
              </div><!--.bl_date-->
              <div class="bl_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div><!--.bl_title-->
               <div class="bl_teaser">
              <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><!--.bl_teaser-->  
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div><!--#bp-->
             <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php } else{ ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>


                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php } ?>
        </div><!-- #post (or #ie) -->  

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>  

        </div><!-- #bottom-wrapper-page -->
```

And my output:

```
03/05/12
 Cool Post 1
 /*
  Template Name: All posts
  */
   ?>
    $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
    ?>
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
     foreach($myposts as $post) :
      ?>
    : 03/05/12
   Test Post
   /*
    Template Name: All posts
    */
     ?>
    $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
     ?>
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
    ?>
     : 19/04/12
     Hello world!
    /*
    Template Name: All posts
    */
   ?>
   $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
    ?>
   $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
     foreach($myposts as $post) :
    ?>
     :
```

Whatever it is, it's messing with my css as well. I noticed he /* Template Name: All posts */, but I don't have a template (to my knowledge) named all posts, so I don't know where this code came from. If anyone could please lend a hand, I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Is this the *actual* output of the page? It looks like you have a bunch of broken/unopened PHP tags there.  Also, I don't see you calling `the_content()` in your first code block at all ...

Comment: thanks for bringing that to my attention EAMann.  I forgot to add the_content() call in this question. But that is the actual output of the page even with the appropriate call.  I've edited my op to reflect the call to the_content().

Comment: Can You edit the question and post all the code, you are not calling `the_content()` and from the output is seems like there is some `echo` and some php tags not closed, the `<?php the_time('d/m/y'); ?>` mentioned by george will not cause such output

Comment: Can you post the contents of the entire file that includes this code?  From the looks of things, the `foreach` is executing properly, but then it's displaying another `foreach` inline ... There might be some strange `echo`ing going on, but without seeing what comes before this code block or knowing how the block is included by WP, I can't be sure.

Comment: You've got it. I just added the entire file

Comment: @Kyle Does the issue persist if you change to the default theme and disable all plugins?

Comment: @m0r7if3r yes, unfortunately it does.

Comment: @Kyle Has it ever worked? What versions of PHP and MySQL are you running?

Comment: @m0r7if3r - the_content() has worked for other pages before, but never for this one. I've also noticed that the other pages do not show up anymore. php ver 5.3 and MySQL ver 5.0

Comment: @Kyle Do a reinstall of wordpress (there's a one-button way of doing it from the Updates menu). Also, make sure your MySQL is version 5.0.15 or greater, as per the [wordpress requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress)

Comment: @m0r7if3r Reinstall completed, SQL Ver 5.0.92 - still having issues

Comment: From the looks of things, this is something that needs some hand's on support. I recommend you take the conversation to the [official support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) and I'll close the question here as "Too localized."  Not a bad thing, just a way of pointing out that this kind of question needs to be moved to a better venue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's happening here. You need to add a ; after the time -

```
<?php the_time('d/m/y'); ?>
```

Even though I'm a bit surprised you got an output at all.

Comment: I see what you mean george, and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it did not solve my issue. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that the code you pasted above don't relate to the actual output so it's just guessing. Are you child theming this?

Comment: No, I'm not child theming. How is it that the date and title's display though?

Comment: the date and title are displaying because the php tags are properly closed... but somewhere in your code there's either an unclosed tag or return or even echo .... can you edit your question and post all the code like user983248 suggested?

Comment: Sure thing george.n, I've just done so.

Comment: Well in regards to the template all php code is closed appropriately and that code should not give that output. There must be a template file that is entitled All Posts... As far as I know WordPress does not fall back to some theme file especially when it's not a child theme. So I'd suggest to go through your theme folder and find the culprit file.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that as well. I looked through the theme folder, but I don't have a file by that name (there's not that many files in the theme folder)

Comment: Sorry didn't make that clear. Wordpress does not fall back to some predefined theme if you are not child theming but it does follow a template hierarchy - so there may be a file there that it's falling on to - check this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Ah sorry you posted already... just in case check that link if it helps.